# iOS background Airplay

Tags: ios, iphone, airplay

I'm trying to to airplay video even when the app is in the background.
Is this possible?
I've enabled `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture` for background modes, in app capabilities.
I've also set AVAudioSession category:

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("error");
    }
```

Using Xcode 8.2.1 for iOS 8.1+ (iPhone simulator)

Comment: hey are you able to solve this? please write your solution. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I ran into an issue where unintended code was deactivating my audio session after the AVPlayerViewController came on screen. You could set a symbolic breakpoint on `-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]` to see if anything else is deactivating your session.

Answer (score -2):

Have you inserted a list in .plist file?

---

Required background modes /
itme0 : App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf4ry.png)

Comment: Could you elaborate, just a bit? What .plist this should get into? What items in the .plist? their expected values? this answer is missing a lot.

Comment: Can hardly understand your answer. What List should be inserted in .plist file? Which .plist file? and the "Required background modes / item0: - couldn't you please explain what should go there, and provide an excerpt, or sample? at least reference to documentation?

Comment: OP already specified in post that they've added the required background mode.